# Participant to my events cannot download the calendar on their Outlook

Tags: civievent

This is my trouble:

Participants to my event have completed the registration form, created with CiviCRM 4.4.7.

When they receive the confirmation email, they can also download clicking on **Download iCalendar File.** And it does not work. I tested it myself, trying to download it on Outlook and the link (this one http://events.esn-eu.org/civicrm/event/ical?reset=1&id=61) takes me to a page telling me the following message:

Access denied

You are not authorized to access this page.

What can I do to solve the issue?
Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You need to grant anonymous users the permission "view event info", could you check if it's done on your site?

Comment: So, shall I verify it on my website settings or on CiviCRM?